# re-formatting an unformatted fortran file

Tags: formatting, fortran

I have an "UNFORMATTED" fortran file for which I have written a small subroutine to try and get some information out of (given below). What I would like to do, or like to know if it is possible to do, is to "format" the file called fort.24 into either another formatted, readable, file or a readable print out to the screen.

I thought about just putting in a loop which reads each line of the file after it has been opened and then prints it to the screen but I am not sure how to do this.

Am I correct in thinking that unformatted files can be reformatted or is this "not how it works".

Thank you very much

James

```
  SUBROUTINE mod2

  implicit none

  !     Arguments
  integer :: nset_pw_dipoles, mgvn, stot, gutot, iprnt, iwrite, &
 &           ifail,dip_comp_present(3)
  character(len=11) ::  form_pw_dipoles
  character(len=80) ::  title
  integer, allocatable :: ichl(:), lvchl(:), mvchl(:)
  real(kind=8), allocatable :: evchl(:), escat(:),re_pw_dipoles(:,:,:,:), im_pw_dipoles(:,:,:,:)

  !     Local
  integer :: keydip, nchan, nbound, no_scat_energies, no_components, ierr
  no_components=3
  keydip=24

  open (unit=24,file = "fort.24", form="UNFORMATTED", iostat=ierr, err=100)

  !     Read set header
  !     ----------------
  read(24) keydip, nset_pw_dipoles
  read(24) title
  read(24) mgvn, stot, gutot, nchan, nbound, no_scat_energies, dip_comp_present

  !     Allocate space for channel info arrays
  allocate( ichl(nchan), lvchl(nchan), mvchl(nchan), evchl(nchan), escat(no_scat_energies) )

  read(24) ichl, lvchl, mvchl, evchl, escat

  !     Write Set Body
  !     --------------   

  !     Allocate space for partial wave dipoles
  allocate( re_pw_dipoles(nbound, nchan, no_components, no_scat_energies), &
 &          im_pw_dipoles(nbound, nchan, no_components, no_scat_energies) )

  read(24) re_pw_dipoles
  read(24) im_pw_dipoles

  return

  100 stop "ERROR: Reading partial wave dipoles"

  END SUBROUTINE mod2
```

Comment: No, you can't format an unformatted file.  What you can do is read the unformatted file and write its contents into a formatted file.  If you want you could then delete the unformatted file, rename the new file to the old file's name and pass it off as the same file, but formatted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I tried reading each line of the file as a string and then printing this string to the screen but this crashed the program. Do you have any advice on how to do this?  (character(len=80) :: title1, title2......  \\ read(24) title1 ...... print *,title1)

Comment: The error is caused by trying to read as a string lines from the unformatted file which are actually some integers.

Comment: In order to read an "unformatted" fortran file you need to know exactly how it was written. If you don't know the exact sequence of data types written to the file it can be quite difficult  to figure out.  The answer to the specific question in the title though is of course once you have the data you can create a new file with whatever format you like.